# Windows XP installation problem with Dell laptop

Tags: windows-xp, installation, setup

AFter the first part of the Windows XP setup on my Dell laptop, it does not respond to the Enter button (i.e. *Press enter to install Windows XP* does not work). The Enter button works well in BIOS but not during set up.

Sometimes it goes thruogh but after the reboot to continue setup it comes to the stop screen and does not complete the installation. Sometimes I also hear this continous beep sound during the beginning of the setup.

It can detect the hard drive but cannot complete set after first setup reboot.

Comment: Dell laptop model ? xp version ?

Answer (score 1):

Either there's a big hardware problem, or the installation CD that you're using is bad, or you're using the wrong CD for your computer.

Please elaborate on what exactly you're doing, which CD you're using, and which Dell computer you have.